# ChartJS 3 vertical annotations

Tags: javascript, annotations, chart.js

I am trying to upgrade my chartjs to v3 and with that the annotations plugin. Tried a few different ways but just cannot seem to get the vertical annotation to show. Tried explicitilty adding xScaleID/yScaleID but I believe that in v3 x/y are the new defaults so would have expected those to be the defaults anyway.

Simplified the whole thing down to this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gray_niall/8t2fj1c5/76/)

```js
const data = {
  "labels": [
    "07/09/2020",
    "14/09/2020",
    "21/09/2020",
    "28/09/2020",
    "05/10/2020",
    "19/10/2020",
    "02/11/2020",
    "09/11/2020",
    "16/11/2020",
    "23/11/2020",
    "30/11/2020",
    "07/12/2020",
    "14/12/2020",
    "04/01/2021",
    "11/01/2021",
    "18/01/2021",
    "25/01/2021",
    "01/02/2021",
    "08/02/2021",
    "22/02/2021",
    "01/03/2021",
    "08/03/2021",
    "15/03/2021",
    "22/03/2021",
    "29/03/2021",
    "19/04/2021",
    "26/04/2021",
    "03/05/2021",
    "10/05/2021",
    "17/05/2021",
    "24/05/2021",
    "07/06/2021",
    "14/06/2021",
    "21/06/2021"
  ],
  "datasets": [{
    "label": [
      "Information"
    ],
    "data": [
      "90",
      "92",
      "94.29",
      "100",
      "100",
      "93.85",
      "90",
      "95.38",
      "90",
      "98.95",
      "100",
      "100",
      "100",
      null,
      null,
      "60",
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      "80",
      "100",
      null,
      "100",
      null,
      "80",
      "100",
      null,
      "100",
      "100",
      "100",
      "100",
      "100",
      "100"
    ],
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)'
  }]
}

var chart = new Chart('chart1', {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    bezierCurve: false,
    spanGaps: true,
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: {
    annotation: {
      annotations: {
        line1: {
          type: 'line',
          mode: 'vertical',
          xMin: '09/11/2020',
          xMax: '09/11/2020',
          borderColor: "#56A6A6",
          borderWidth: 10
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/1.4.0/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart1" height="400">

</canvas>
```

If anyone has any ideas then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you configured the options in the wrong space, the plugin options have to go inside of the options object. The plugins section what you used is for an array containing inline plugins, secondly you need to include the annotation plugin after chart.js since chart.js needs to be loaded first because the annotation plugin uses some functions from chart.js:

```js
const data = {
  "labels": [
    "07/09/2020",
    "14/09/2020",
    "21/09/2020",
    "28/09/2020",
    "05/10/2020",
    "19/10/2020",
    "02/11/2020",
    "09/11/2020",
    "16/11/2020",
    "23/11/2020",
    "30/11/2020",
    "07/12/2020",
    "14/12/2020",
    "04/01/2021",
    "11/01/2021",
    "18/01/2021",
    "25/01/2021",
    "01/02/2021",
    "08/02/2021",
    "22/02/2021",
    "01/03/2021",
    "08/03/2021",
    "15/03/2021",
    "22/03/2021",
    "29/03/2021",
    "19/04/2021",
    "26/04/2021",
    "03/05/2021",
    "10/05/2021",
    "17/05/2021",
    "24/05/2021",
    "07/06/2021",
    "14/06/2021",
    "21/06/2021"
  ],
  "datasets": [{
    "label": [
      "Information"
    ],
    "data": [
      "90",
      "92",
      "94.29",
      "100",
      "100",
      "93.85",
      "90",
      "95.38",
      "90",
      "98.95",
      "100",
      "100",
      "100",
      null,
      null,
      "60",
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      "80",
      "100",
      null,
      "100",
      null,
      "80",
      "100",
      null,
      "100",
      "100",
      "100",
      "100",
      "100",
      "100"
    ],
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)'
  }]
}

var chart = new Chart('chart1', {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      annotation: {
        annotations: {
          line1: {
            type: 'line',
            mode: 'vertical',
            xMin: '09/11/2020',
            xMax: '09/11/2020',
            borderColor: "#56A6A6",
            borderWidth: 10
          }
        }
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    bezierCurve: false,
    spanGaps: true,
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/1.4.0/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart1" height="400">

</canvas>
```